# Workflow configured for mail sending to user when document adding in SharePoint 2010

Tags: list, sharepoint-2010, smtp, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-workflow

i need to send email via workflow here i have configured workflow for when document adding, then need to mail send to admin.
here workflow is correct but mail is unable sending to admin.

i haven't configured SMTP outgoing email in CA IN SharePoint2010.
do i have required any smtp configuration ple suggest me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to configure the SMTP settings in Central Administration.

Here is a guide on how to do it:

http://hosting.com/support/sharepoint-2010/configure-emailsmtp-in-sharepoint-2010/

1. Go to Central Administration Console
2. In Central Administration, click System Settings.
3. On the System Settings page, in the E-Mail and Text Messages (SMS) section, click Configure outgoing e-mail settings.
4. On the Outgoing E-Mail Settings page, in the Mail Settings section, type the SMTP server name for outgoing e-mail (for example, mail.example.com) in the Outbound SMTP server box.
5. In the From address box, type the e-mail address as you want it to be displayed to e-mail recipients.
6. In the Reply-to address box, type the e-mail address to which you want e-mail recipients to reply.
7. Click OK and you are done